# My dropdown menu doesn't activate correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add my dropdown menu to some dynamically created html content using javascript. I have a table that I fill with data based on something returned from a .json file. I want the table data to be filled with my drop-down menu.

The thing is the classes that I add in the Jquery string don't get applied. For example:

`infores = afile.json` and always returns text

**setup.js**

```
//add table rows
if (isMobile.any()) {
    //$("#probes").css("column-count: 2");
    activ_col_count = small_col_count;
    num_probe_rows = Math.ceil(infores.outputs.length / small_col_count) * 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < num_probe_rows; i++) {
        ;
        $("#probes").append(`<tr></tr>`)
    }
} else {
    //$("#probes").css("column-count: 13");
    activ_col_count = big_col_count;
    num_probe_rows = Math.ceil(infores.outputs.length / big_col_count) * 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < num_probe_rows; i++) {
        ;
        $("#probes").append("<tr></tr>")
    }
}

let table_rows = document.getElementById('probes').children;

//fills rows with correct number of data
for (let i = 0; i < num_probe_rows; i = i + 2) {
    for (let j = 0; j < activ_col_count; j++) {

        if (i == num_probe_rows - 2 && j == infores.outputs.length % activ_col_count) {
            break;
        }

        table_rows[i].innerHTML += `
                            <td>
                                <h2> <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button onclick="showDropdown()" class="dropbtn">${(infores.outputs[i+j].isenabled)?(infores.outputs[i+j].isrunning?"Running":"Enabled"):"Disabled"}</button>
                                        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" ${drop_show?"":"hidden"}>
                                            <p>Running</p>
                                            <p>Enabled</p>
                                            <p>Disabled</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </h2>
                                ${infores.outputs[i+j].name}
                            </td>
                        `;
        table_rows[i + 1].innerHTML += `<td>${infores.outputs[i+j].settemp}</td>`;

    }
}
```

I keep a boolean named `drop_show`.

I also have these events:

```
function showDropdown() {
  drop_show = !drop_show;
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        drop_show = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content p{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content p:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

**html**

```
<table class="settings" id="probes">
    
</table>
```

The paragraphs just show all the time and are not affected at all by clicking.

I feel like I'm doing things wrong here lol please help

Comment: Please show your markup, even if it is just an empty element with an ID attribute. Use the editor to build a functioning snippet. That's a lot of code to imagine working.

Comment: okay i think that's enough

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: You did not build a functioning snippet. Is there some reason you can't?